# Recreating a sentence using two text files (Python)

Tags: python

I have two text files. One called 'textfile' and the other called 'textfile1'. These two texts files contain the words that make up a sentence and the other the positions of the words that make up the sentence in the original sentence. Both are made from two lists.

```
sentence = "This and that, and this and this."
textfile = ['This', 'and', 'that,', 'this', 'this.'
textfile1 = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]
```

I have recreated the sentence using lists. But want to recreate it using the text files. I have tried:

```
wrd = []
num = []
textfile =  open ("words.txt", "r")
for row in textfile:
    wrd.append(row.split())

textfile1 =  open ("positions.txt", "r")
for i in textfile1:
    num.append(int(i.strip()))

recreated = ' '.join(wrd[pos] for pos in num)
textfile2 = open ("recreated.txt", "wt") #opening a new text file in write mode
textfile2.write (recreated)
textfile2.close() #closing the text file
```

However this did not work. I would like to recreate the original sentence using the contents of the two text files. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to write the sentence to `textfile2`.

Comment: Also convert the tokens from textfile1 to integers if you use them as list indexes!

Comment: That error has been fixed. However when I run the code I get the error: 'list indices must be integers or slices not strings. @Carsten

Comment: Your first loop is iterating over lines, not words.

Comment: @Hackndo How do I fix this? I thought that problem would have been resolved with .strip.

Comment: I posted an answer with your issues, how to solve them, and how you could refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi, I see two mistakes.

First your loops are iterating over rows, not words

```
for row in textfile:
    wrd += row.split()
```

is a good way to get all your words.

Then you are appending some strings to num, not int.

```
for i in textfile1:
    row = [int(j) for j in i.split()]
    num += row
```

is a way to have integer indexes and sticking to your code, even if I would consider refactoring it.

Here is an idea :

```
words = list()
num = list()
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        words += line.split()

with open("positions.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        num += [int(i) for i in line.split()]

recreated = ' '.join(words[pos] for pos in num)

with open("recreated.txt", "wt") as f:
    f.write(recreated)
```

Comment: This code works exactly how I want it to. However is there a need for the 'with' when opening the files? Could you also give a brief description as to why my code did not work. Many thanks.

Comment: `with`statement handles the opening **and closing** for you. It improves code maintenance and readability. Now for your code, I thought that the beginning of my answer would answer your question. When you iterate over a file handle (`textfile`, `textfile1`,`textfile2`) it iterates over the lines. `strip` only removes your chosen char at the beginning and end of your string. `split(separator)` splits your string into a list, when `separator` is encountered. So you need to loop through every line and split them with the space (default) separator. End of your code was correct, just refactored it.

Comment: Further reading about [with statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: I have tried running the code exactly as you have shown here but it does not create the recreated.txt text file. Can you help?

Comment: Well, I can try. Which python version are you using ? Which editor/IDE ? How do you run this code ? Does the file **recreated.txt** already exists ? You can also remove the `t` in `open("recreated.txt", "wt")` so you have `open("recreated.txt", "w")`. If **recreated.txt** already exists, check that you have rights to write (modify) it.

Comment: Python 3.4. I am using notepad++.

Comment: Well then just try `with open("recreated2.txt", "w") as f: f.write("Hello World!")`in a new python file. If it does not create and write to the file, then it means a new questions should be asked on stackoverflow :D

Comment: Well I have tried to write "Hello world" to a file and it has worked. I have no idea what is wrong with my writing in my main program.

Comment: Copy/paste your entire program in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and send it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106962/discussion-between-r-mcevoy-and-hackndo).

Answer (score 0):

You read strings from `textfile1` (if you really do read them from a file unlike in the code you posted where `textfile1` is a list). A short version could look like:

```
wrd = open('textfile', 'r').read().strip().split()
num = [int(token) for token in open('textfile1', 'r').read().strip().split()]

with open('textfile2', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join([wrd[i] for i in num))
```

Comment: It gives the error: 'invalid literal for int() with base 10'

Comment: You might have to strip the lines. Bur if the file really does contain only one number per line, it should work.

Comment: How does `textfile1` actually look?

Comment: Blank because the program crashes.

Comment: sorry, I mean `textfile1`

Comment: Just the numbers with spaces inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file that looks like this

```
This
and
that
this
this
```

You can do this,

```
file1 = open('file.txt', 'r')
print list(l.strip() for l in file1)
```

Which prints,

```
['This', 'and', 'that', 'this', 'this']
```

And if you have a file like this,

```
This and that this this
```

You can do,

```
file1.readline().split()
```

Which basically gives the same output. And you can do same things for the other file and get two lists like you specified in your question. Now, you can go ahead and recreate your sentence,

```
textfile = ['This', 'and', 'that,', 'this', 'this.']
textfile1 = ['0', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4']
recreated = ' '.join(textfile[int(pos)] for pos in textfile1)
```

And finally write it back to another file,

```
open("recreated.txt", "wt").write(recreated)
```